# Error:' ActiveX Cannot Create Object' When Connecting VBA to Adobe Acrobat

Tags: excel, vba, adobe, acrobat

Im attempting to connect Adobe Acrobat to Excel Via VBA. The Goal is to take a PDF and insert it into Excel.

```
Sub Imp_Into_XL(PDF_File As String, Each_Sheet As Boolean)

'This procedure get the PDF data into excel by following way
'1.Open PDF file
'2.Looping through pages
'3.get the each PDF page data into individual _
  sheets or single sheet as defined in Each_Sheet Parameter

Dim AC_PD As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc              'access pdf file
Dim AC_Hi As Acrobat.AcroHiliteList         'set selection word count
Dim AC_PG As Acrobat.AcroPDPage             'get the particular page
Dim AC_PGTxt As Acrobat.AcroPDTextSelect    'get the text of selection area

Dim WS_PDF As Worksheet
Dim RW_Ct As Long                           'row count
Dim Col_Num As Integer                      'column count
Dim Li_Row As Long                          'Maximum rows limit for one column
Dim Yes_Fir As Boolean                      'to identify beginning of page

Li_Row = Rows.Count

Dim Ct_Page As Long                         'count pages in pdf file
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long         'looping variables
Dim T_Str As String
Dim Hld_Txt As Variant                      'get PDF total text into array

RW_Ct = 0                                   'set the intial value
Col_Num = 1                                 'set the intial value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set AC_PD = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc 'ERROR LINE HERE
Set AC_Hi = New Acrobat.AcroHiliteList
```

I get an Runtime Error 429: ActiveX Component Can't Create Object on the line with Set AC_PD = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc. I'm not sure what's causing it. I'm pretty sure I have all the correct references. Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you replace `Set AC_PD = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc` by `Set AC_PD = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")` Do you still get the error?

Comment: That doesn't work either, same error on that line, thanks for the reply though!

Comment: I can think of couple of reasons for this. **1.** There is something wrong with your Adobe installation. OR **2.** You are working from an Office PC and your login doesn't have enough Rights.

Comment: There may be other reasons but these are the 2 which I could immediately think of...

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthRout ! I'll try and work some things out with IT!

Comment: If you want to narrow it down to #2 then ask one of your IT guys to start Excel (Right Click - Runs as Administrator) and now try the code. If the code runs then it definitely is #2 :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for anyone that comes across this is to buy Adobe Acrobat Pro. Runs perfectly with it since you can only get the exact right references with Pro.